# Import module in D from a sister folder?

Tags: d

Suppose I have the following directory structure for the project:

```
myproj/dir1/file1.d
myproj/dir2/file2.d
myproj/main.d
```

How can I import `main` and `file2` modules within the source file `file1.d`?

Comment: Read http://dlang.org/module.html and http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/modules.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file1.d will have `module dir1.file1;` line , file2.d will have `module dir2.file2;` line and main.d will start with `module main;`.

Module declarations above will tell D what to do when it encounters line like:  `import main, dir2.file2;`;

As suggested by @sigod , read the http://dlang.org/module.html for more information.

Comment: Important point relevant to question: module paths in D are relative to configured import path, not path where module file is located.

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун how do you configure import path?

Comment: BY using `-I` compiler flag. When looking for imports it tries all configured import paths one by one until needed file is found with import path as root and module name turned into relative path. Once there is a match, rest is ignored.